# Modifying vlc source code on osx 10.9

Tags: c, macos, makefile, vlc

I apologize for the ignorant question (I am out of my depth). I'm trying to tinker around a bit with vlc on osx 10.9. I followed the instructions on the wiki to compile from source and everything worked fine.

What I would like to do ideally is to modify the playlist generation of the vlc player, but right now I'm just trying to figure out the codebase. To start, I chmod 777'd vlc.c, tried inserting some print statements in vlc.c and then did make in the build directory. The changes to the code don't appear.

Could someone give me an idea of what the process would be to modify source files and recompile?